# Can you set specific apps to NOT auto update on iOS?

Tags: ios, applications

I have auto update on for apps on my iPhone iOS 9.3 but I'd like to set certain apps not to update. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to set auto update for specific apps.  You have to turn Auto Update off at the App Store level then review each update notice you receive to determine if you want to update that app or not.